# Sort list of tuples based on multiple criteria

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

Given a list of tuples, [(x, y, z), ....., (x_n, y_n,z_n)], x, y are nonnegative number and z is either 0 or 1, I want to sort the list based on the following three criteria-

1. if x_i != x_j, sort on ascendening order of x(tuple[0])
2. if x_i == x_j and z_i != z_j, sort on ascendening order of z(tuple[2])
3. if x_i == x_j and z_i == z_j and z_i == 0, sort on descending order of y(tuple[1])
4. if x_i == x_j and z_i == z_j and z_i == 1, sort on ascending order of y(tuple[1])

> ```
> Input: [(1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (1, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1)]
> output:[(1, 3, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1)]
> ```

Since Python 3 does not support custom comparator function for sort as I know for JAVA, I do not know how to incorporate the above three criteria in the sort method.

I can sort based on the two criteria (either 1,2 or 1,3) of the above-mentioned criterion. Adding the third criteria makes one of 2 or 3 invalid. I am adding my code here-

```
points.sort(key=lambda p: p[2])        
points.sort(key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)
points.sort(key=lambda p: p[0])
```

> ```
> OUTPUT: [(1, 3, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1)] (criteria 3 not satisfied)
> ```

Can anybody suggest, what should be the value of key argument in this situation? Thanks

Comment: `points.sort(key=lambda p: (p[0], -p[1], p[2]))` is what you want?

Comment: No, it will not satisfy criteria 3. Thanks

Comment: Criteria 2 and 3 contradict each other. How would you sort `[(0, 3, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 1, 1)]`? It's impossible with your criteria.

Comment: yes, they contradict if you ignore tuple[2]. Using cmp function you can handle it. However, i did not yet get any way to do it with key function

Comment: What do you mean with "if you ignore tuple[2]"? And again, how would you sort the example I asked about?

Comment: z, tupple[2] values are different for criteria 3 and 4. Btw I edited the criteria to make it clear. I was trying to do it only using key function since cmp support is removed from python 3. However, if I use transitional compare function cmp_to_key, using following compare function, it will satisfy all of the above criteria

Comment: def compare(self, t1, t2):
        if t1[0] != t2[0]:
            return t1[0] -t2[0]
        elif t1[0] == t2[0] and t1[2] != t2[2]: #equal start and end
            return t1[2] - t2[2]
        elif t1[0] == t2[0] and t1[2] == t2[2] and t1[2] == 0:#equal start
            return t2[1] - t1[1]
        else: # equal end
            return t1[1] - t2[1]

Comment: Your edit didn't make it "clear" but made it *possible*. You *changed* the definition. And now it's just yet another boring custom sort with an easy key :-P. Well ok, a bit less boring than the average one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encoding your criteria...

```
points.sort(key=lambda p: (p[0], p[2], p[1] if p[2] else -p[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have truly ridiculously complicated sorting rules, you can just write a comparator function, then [use `functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to make it into a valid `key` argument. So write your insane comparator function, add `from functools import cmp_to_key` to the top of your file, then do:

```
points.sort(key=cmp_to_key(my_insane_comparator))
```

and it will work as expected. All `cmp_to_key` really does is make a custom class with a custom `__lt__` (less than operator) that performs the work of the comparator in the `__lt__` on each comparison.

Comment: does that mean, I can not do it without using transition function cmp_to_key? Since cmp is removed in Python 3 ,  I assumed it can be still done using only the key function. Thanks

Comment: @MohiuddinSohel: You could hand-write your own wrapper class that defines `__lt__` to accomplish the same feat, but `cmp_to_key` lets you focus on writing a single function rather than the whole class (it does the wrapper class boilerplate work for you).